# Speech Recognition module not working, despite being downloaded

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I was following along a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/AWvsXxDtEkU) where they used the SpeechRecognition module, but when I made it to the [first test](https://youtu.be/AWvsXxDtEkU?t=317) it returns `C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Fatawi\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Fatawi/main.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Fatawi\main.py", line 1, in <module> import speech_recognition as sr ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'`

I've tried reinstalling the library multiple times along with the PyAudio library. I ran the test that PyPi has for it and it works, but I don't know how fix it from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your python interpreter environment (the python version that's run the python file) maybe it's not the same version as python when you downloaded Speech Recognition.
2. Check if you activating the environemt.

For better understand see this [blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-virtual-environment-using-venv-python/) in geeks for geeks  might help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I followed the guide to my best understanding and from what I can tell there is no difference between the virtual and original environment. When you say "... activating the environment" I'm assuming you meant the virtual one. I pip install for both environments, and both version align with the official update.

Answer (score 1):

So aftergoing through some of the settings of the project file and checking the Python Interpreter it didn't have the SpeechRecognition Package. So I'm assuming that something went wrong with the install.

Thank you Faisal Faraj for the help.